# Why it says what types are incovariant in this code?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, prototypal-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

TArrayInt is a child of TArray, why I can't return it in polymorph functions?

```
template <class T>
class TArray {
public:
    virtual T& operator[](int index) = 0;
    virtual void push_back(T num) = 0;
    virtual TArray operator+=(T num) = 0;
    virtual TArray operator+(T num) = 0;
    int size();
    void print();
};

class TArrayInt :public TArray<int> {
    vector<int> array;
public:
    int& operator[](int index);
    void push_back(int num);
    TArrayInt operator+=(int num); //here is an error
    TArrayInt operator+(int num); //and here too
};
```

Comment: Is there a way in c++ to make this code without using templates?
How can I override operator[] without knowing what type it is?

Comment: Do you really want inheritance? Do you want several children classes inheriting from `TArray<int>`?

Comment: Seeing the discussion under the answer I believe you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve using these classes? Why do you want to use `TArray<int>*` interchangibly with `TArray<float>*`?

Answer (score 0):

Covariant return types must be pointers or references. You probably want those operators to return references:

```
template <class T>
class TArray {
public:
  // ...
  virtual TArray& operator+=(T num) = 0;
  virtual TArray& operator+(T num) = 0;
};

class TArrayInt : public TArray<int> {
public:
  // ...
  TArrayInt& operator+=(int num);
  TArrayInt& operator+(int num);
};
```

Comment: `operator+` returning a reference would be weird.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Good point.

Comment: also, how i can make an abstract class here without templates?

Comment: @Givikap120 Why don't you want to use templates? If you don't use templates then the code becomes very complicated and ugly (lots of `void*` and type erasure boilerplate). Is there a problem you're running into using templates?

Comment: @DavidG how use this:
TArray* ptr = new TArrayInt;
while using templates?

Comment: @Givikap120 `TArray<int>* ptr = new TArrayInt` is how you would write it.

Comment: @DavidG i know that, but in this case, i can't do this:
ptr = new TArrayFloat;

Comment: @Givikap120 Then make a non-template base class that `TArray<T>` derives from. You can call it `Array`. Then you can do `Array* ptr = new TArrayInt; ptr = new TArrayFloat;` if you want.

Comment: @Givikap120 But in my opinion it doesn't look like you need to make specific `TArrayInt`, `TArrayFloat`, `TArrayDouble`, etc... classes. Why not just use `TArray<int>`, `TArray<float>`, and `TArray<double>` directly?

Comment: @DavidG but i want to use TArray interface. I can't use TArray functions if ptr has Array type, doesn't it?

Comment: @Givikap120 Ah, I see.

Comment: @DavidG about the second message. I am learning polymorphism, and want to know how to use abstract classes and different return types methods.

Comment: @Givikap120 I don't think this is the best example to learn it. In C++ we have the `std::vector<T>` class which is a class template for an array. You would never do something like `vector<int> arr = {1,2,3}; arr = {"a","b","c"};` because the types don't match and we know that. There's also no way to do it with templates, and no elegant way to do it with non-templates.